# last coordinates value return zero

Tags: python, list

The last_coordinate[] values return zero when it is suppose to return the previous values of the coordinates[] . Its reading its data live from a camera which tells the coordinates of the object detected. The reason for me to implement the last_coordinates values it to compare the previous coordinate values and the new coordinate values to differentiate them and execute an action. How do i fix this?

```
    import socket
    import os,sys
    import time
    from threading import Thread

    HOST = '59.191.193.67'
    PORT = 5555

    coordinates = []

    def connect():   
        globals()['client_socket'] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect((HOST,PORT))

    def update_coordinates():
        screen_width = 0
        screen_height = 0
        global last_coordinates
        last_coordinates = [0 for _ in range(19)]
        while True:
            try:
                client_socket.send("loc\n")
                data = client_socket.recv(8192)
            except:
                connect();
                continue;

            globals()['coordinates'] = data.split()
            if(not(coordinates[-1] == "eom" and coordinates[0] == "start")):
                continue

            if (screen_width != int(coordinates[2])):
                    screen_width = int(coordinates[2])
                    screen_height = int(coordinates[3])
                    return

            if (coordinates != last_coordinates):
                 return last_coordinates[16:19]
            last_coordinates = coordinates[:]



Thread(target=update_coordinates).start()
```

Comment: Too much code. Cut out what is not relevant to the subject matter.

Comment: @defuz what should i cut out? mind editing it?

Comment: I do not quite understand what is the actual question. The code is too difficult to understand. Put exact question. What does not work? What's not to like?

Comment: If your `update_coordinates()` is properly formatted the `if` after the `while` is never executed because `while` only exits via a `return` in your code. There is at least another one intendation error after `if (screen_width != int(coordinates[2])):`.

Comment: Addendum to defuz's comment: remove all the `*robot*` functions, you don't use them. No `Thread()` needed either, just remove. Addendum to halex's comment: your indentation is badly messed up: the line below the `if` (before the `return` at the end of the `while` loop) is not indented, for example (and the next line is indented twice).

Comment: Why do you `return` from a loop that seems like it should run forever?

Comment: @nneonneo so what should i do about it?

Comment: Returning the `last_coordinate[]` values to what?